# PHP Class to Generate HTML?

Tags: php, html

Anyone know of any classes written for php that can clean up your code a bit?

Something like,

```
$htGen = new HTMLGenerator();
$htGen->newDOM('div', 'here is what goes in the div', 'optionalID', 'optionalClass');
```

Or does that just sound redundant?

I end up with some complex looking mish-mashes of html and php sometimes that I feel could be simplified a bit eg my latest cms bit;

```
foreach($details as $detail){

    $d = unserialize($detail);

    if($ad){
        print_r($d); // <-- VIEW DETAIL OBJECT IN WHOLE.
    }else{
    if($d->get_info('orphan')){
        echo '<li class="classRow orphan">' . "\n";
        echo '<div class="orphan" style="display:none">orphan</div>' . "\n";
    }else{
        echo '<li class="classRow">' . "\n";
        echo '<div class="orphan" style="display:none"></div>' . "\n";
    }

        echo '<div  class="classNumbers" id="' . $d->get_info('class ID') .  '" style="display:none"></div>' . "\n"; 
        echo '<div class="rowBG" style="overflow:hidden;width:100%">';   
            echo '<div class="startTime"></div>' . "\n";
            echo '<div class="details"><span class="classes">' . $d->get_info('class number') . '</span> - <input class="detailInput" type="text" value="' . $d->get_info('class description') . '"/><div class="editButton"><a class="editExpand">options(+)</a></div></div>' . "\n";
            echo '<div class="interval">';
            echo '<input class="intervalInput" type="text" value="' . $d->get_info('interval') . '" maxlength="5"/>';
            echo '</div>' . "\n"; 
            echo '<div class="numRiders"><input class="numRidersInput" type="text" value="' . $d->get_info('num riders') . '"/></div>' . "\n"; 
        echo '</div>'; 

        echo '<div class="classOptions">' . "\n";
            echo '<div class="selectRingMove">Move to Ring:<select id="ringSwap"><option>Select A Ring</option>' . get_ring_options() .  '</select></div>' . "\n";
            if($d->get_info('online sign up') != 'false'){
                echo '<div class="signUpContainer">Sign-Up<input type="checkbox" class="signUp" checked/></div>' . "\n";
            }else{
                echo '<div class="signUpContainer">Sign-Up<input type="checkbox" class="signUp"/></div>' . "\n";
            }
            if($d->get_info('water and drag')){
                echo '<div class="wdBoxContainer"><select id="wdDescrip"><option>WATER AND DRAG</option><option>COURSE CHANGE & WALK</option><option>OTHER</option></select><input type="checkbox" class="wdBox" checked/><input type="text" value="' . $d->get_info('water and drag') .  '" maxlength="2" class="wdInput"> min</div>' . "\n";
            }else{
                echo '<div class="wdBoxContainer"><select id="wdDescrip"><option>WATER AND DRAG</option><option>COURSE CHANGE & WALK</option><option>OTHER</option></select><input type="checkbox" class="wdBox"/><input type="text" value="20" maxlength="2" class="wdInput"> min</div>' . "\n";
            }
            if($d->get_info('ghost riders')){
                echo '<div class="ghostRidersContainer">Ghost Riders<input type="checkbox" checked class="ghostBox"><input type="text" maxlength="2" class="ghostRiderInput" value="' . $d->get_info('ghost riders') .  '"></div>' . "\n";
            }else{
                echo '<div class="ghostRidersContainer">Ghost Riders<input type="checkbox" class="ghostBox"><input type="text" maxlength="2" class="ghostRiderInput"></div>' . "\n";
            }

        echo '</div>' . "\n";

    echo '</li>' . "\n";

    if($d->get_info('water and drag')){
        echo '<li class="waterAndDragRow" style="display:block;"><span class="wdStartTime">08:33am</span> - <span class="wdEndTime">08:34am</span> <input type="text" class="wdDescription" value="' . $d->get_info('water and drag description') . '"></li>';
    }
    }
}
```

Or, if you know of a cleaner way to write long blocks of intermingled php vars and html... (not a big fan of EOF>>>)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think doing this for generic HTML is a waste of time and bad for readability, but you could save yourself a lot of time doing this for structured HTML like `select` and `input` with matching `label`.

Comment: You have number of libraries, but being angry that I wasted 2 hours trying to understand one bugged code I decided to write my own. It was just half of day of work, here you go: https://github.com/Ch3shireDev/html-generator

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess it could be done with http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php. But that isn't really a good way to do it.

I agree that your code code sample isn't very clear, you could consider something like:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
    <li>
        <?=$item['something']?>
        <?php if ($item['foo'] == 'bar'): ?>
        <ul>
            <li>bar</li>
        </ul>
        <?php else: ?>
        <ul>
            <li>foo</li>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<ul>
```

That's a lot better imho, I use it like that in my views.

Btw, you should validate your html output. For example, a `div`-element isn't allowed in a `li`-element.

edit:
Obviously, the following code:

```
<?php if ($item['foo'] == 'bar'): ?>
<ul>
    <li>bar</li>
</ul>
<?php else: ?>
<ul>
    <li>foo</li>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Could be replaced by:

```
<ul>
    <li><?=($item['foo'] == 'bar' ? 'bar' : 'foo')?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: +1 I normally don't like to use short tags but this was what I was going to tell me him to do (with normal php tags)

Comment: Short tags are okay, as long as it's enabled on your sever. Some say that they're deprecated and will be deleted in PHP6, that's definitely **NOT** true.

Answer (score 6):

I'm working on a simple DSL that addresses this common task. It's called **htmlgen**, mirrored on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/z1ffy/htmlgen).

Here's an example

```
use function htmlgen\html as h;

h('#wrapper',
  h('h1.title', 'Hello, World'),
  h('p',
    h('comment', 'link to something'),
    h('a', ['href'=>'https://duckduckgo.com'], 'search the internet')
  )
);
```

Here's the output (actual output does not have whitespace)

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1 class="title">Hello, World</h1>
  <p>
    <!-- link to something -->
    <a href="https://duckduckgo.com">search the internet</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

It's very new but at ~200 lines of source, it's already very powerful. Fork it and make adjustments or send me a note with suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

The main idea of generating HTML is to keep HTML as is.
Just divide your script into 2 parts: prepare data part and display data part. A latter one should contain mostly HTML with some PHP control structures. Of course, there should be as less PHP code as possible. Move all unnecessary PHP code into first part.

Well to sum up all of the above:
there should be nothing to unserialize in the $details array. Have your data prepared already

```
<? foreach ($details as $d): ?>              
<li class="classRow orphan">
  <div class="orphan" style="display:none"><? if ($d->get_info('orphan')): ?>orphan<? endif ?></div>
   <div class="classNumbers" id="<?= $d->get_info('class ID') ?>" style="display:none"></div> 
    <div class="rowBG" style="overflow:hidden;width:100%">
     <div class="startTime"></div>
      <div class="details">
       <span class="classes"><?= $d->get_info('class number') ?></span> -
        <input class="detailInput" type="text" value="<?= $d->get_info('class description') ?>"/>
         <div class="editButton">
          <a class="editExpand">options(+)</a>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="interval">
         <input class="intervalInput" type="text" value="<?= $d->get_info('interval') ?>" maxlength="5"/>
        </div>
        <div class="numRiders">
         <input class="numRidersInput" type="text" value="<?= $d->get_info('num riders') ?>"/>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="classOptions">
       <div class="selectRingMove">Move to Ring:
        <select id="ringSwap">
         <option>Select A Ring</option>
<?= foreach (get_ring_options() as $value => $option): ?>
     <option value="<?=$value?>"><?=$option?></option>
<? endforeach ?>
         </select>
       </div>
       <div class="signUpContainer">Sign-Up
        <input type="checkbox" class="signUp" <? if (!$d->get_info('online sign up'): ?>checked<? endif ?>/>
       </div>
```

and so on.

The main rule should be DRY: Do not Repeat Yourself.
Do not repeat blocks of code if there is only one word difference.
But enclose that word into condition

Note that  get_ring_options() was replaced with proper code.
Do not make functions that return HTML, but an array instead.

Comment: btw.. $details is an array of serialized objects... hence the unserialze().  Obviously you couldn't have known that ;)

Comment: @Jascha it is obvious from the code. but it should not be serialized. Why to serialize at all? Make it array of objects. I've added some explanations to the answer

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel, I'm serializing it because it's data going in and out of a database.

Comment: @Jascha serializing data that is going in and out of a database is **especially prohibited**. Anyway, you have to prepare your data first. Data preparation - first part. Data output - second part. DO NOT MIX

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel,  Also, this is all part of a method named pring_list() buried in a class ScheduleUtils.  My end product is <html><body><?php print_list(); ?></body></html> (simplified example).

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel. Could you elaborate on the prohibition?  I found it the simplest solution as I had an array of objects that I didn't want to break down into table columns.  My process was to serialize my object, insert it in an array, json_encode that array and then real_escape my json_encoded array.  It let me store large chunks of data in one column, rather than creating a whole table to store all of my objects vars.  Does that sound completely wrong?

Comment: @Jascha yes, that's right words: sound completely wrong. Database IS designed to have many columns and make relations and calculations between them. The way you are using a database, you don't need a database at all.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a class, consider a library of functions to generate HTML. I didn't use a class to make the code that you end up writing concise but expressive. With a class you must create an instance and use that variable, or make the methods static and write static references.

With this technique creating HTML for an image that is a link looks like this:

```
a('/example/url', img('image_url', $altText));
```

This is based on a script I once created. First the generic functions to generate HTML elements and attributes:

```
function tag($tag, $text, $attributes = array()) {
    return "<$tag" . attributesToArray($attributes) . ">$text</$tag>";
}

function minimizedTag($tag, $attributes = array()) {
    return "<$tag" . attributesToArray($attributes) . " />";
}

function attributesToArray($attributes = array()){
    $a = '';
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute => $value) {
        $a .= " $attribute='$value'";
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Then add functions named according to the HTML elements they create, like a() and img() to create a link and image:

```
function a($link, $text, $attributes = array()) {
    $a = array('href' => $link);
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute => $value) {
        $a[$attribute] = $value;
    }
    return tag('a', $text, $a);
}

function img($url, $alt = null) {
    $a = array('src' => $url);
    if (!is_null($alt)){
        if (is_array($alt)){
            $a = array_merge($a, $alt);
        } else {
            $a['alt'] = $alt;
        }
    }
    return minimizedTag('img', $a);
}
```

Choose the parameters to pass common attributes wisely to make the library easier to use.

Comment: That reminds me of the late Doug Clifton, from whom I learned the basics of PHP. He also wrote something like that: http://loadaveragezero.com/vnav/labs/PHP/markup.php

Answer (score 2):

I'll probably get downvoted for recommending short tags, but here's what I do. I put all the `<?` and `?>` tags at column 1 so that the code reads like a mix of PHP and HTML. No `echo` statements is the goal.

```
    foreach ($details as $detail) {
        $d = unserialize($detail);

        if ($ad) {
            print_r($d); // <-- VIEW DETAIL OBJECT IN WHOLE.
        }
        else {
            if ($d->get_info('orphan')) {
?>              <li class="classRow orphan">
                  <div class="orphan" style="display:none">orphan</div>
<?          }
            else {
?>              <li class="classRow">
                  <div class="orphan" style="display:none"></div>
<?          }

?>          <div class="classNumbers" id="<?= $d->get_info('class ID') ?>"
                 style="display:none"></div> 
            <div class="rowBG" style="overflow:hidden;width:100%">
              <div class="startTime"></div>
              <div class="details">
                <span class="classes"><?= $d->get_info('class number') ?></span> -
                <input class="detailInput" type="text" value="<?= $d->get_info('class description') ?>"/>
                <div class="editButton">
                  <a class="editExpand">options(+)</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="interval">
                <input class="intervalInput" type="text" value="<?= $d->get_info('interval') ?>" maxlength="5"/>
              </div>
              <div class="numRiders">
                <input class="numRidersInput" type="text" value="<?= $d->get_info('num riders') ?>"/>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="classOptions">
              <div class="selectRingMove">
                Move to Ring:
                <select id="ringSwap">
                  <option>Select A Ring</option>
                  <?= get_ring_options() ?>
                </select>
              </div>

<?            if ($d->get_info('online sign up') != 'false') {
?>                <div class="signUpContainer">
                    Sign-Up
                    <input type="checkbox" class="signUp" checked/>
                  </div>
<?            }
              else {
?>                <div class="signUpContainer">
                    Sign-Up
                    <input type="checkbox" class="signUp"/>
                  </div>
<?            }

              if ($d->get_info('water and drag')) {
?>                <div class="wdBoxContainer">
                    <select id="wdDescrip">
                      <option>WATER AND DRAG</option>
                      <option>COURSE CHANGE &amp; WALK</option>
                      <option>OTHER</option>
                    </select>

                    <input type="checkbox" class="wdBox" checked/>
                    <input type="text" value="<?= $d->get_info('water and drag') ?>" maxlength="2" class="wdInput"> min
                  </div>
<?            }
              else {
?>                <div class="wdBoxContainer">
                    <select id="wdDescrip">
                      <option>WATER AND DRAG</option>
                      <option>COURSE CHANGE &amp; WALK</option>
                      <option>OTHER</option>
                    </select>

                    <input type="checkbox" class="wdBox"/>
                    <input type="text" value="20" maxlength="2" class="wdInput"> min
                  </div>
<?            }

              if ($d->get_info('ghost riders')) {
?>                <div class="ghostRidersContainer">
                    Ghost Riders
                    <input type="checkbox" checked class="ghostBox">
                    <input type="text" maxlength="2" class="ghostRiderInput" value="<?= $d->get_info('ghost riders') ?>">
                  </div>
<?            }
              else {
?>                <div class="ghostRidersContainer">
                    Ghost Riders
                    <input type="checkbox" class="ghostBox">
                    <input type="text" maxlength="2" class="ghostRiderInput">
                  </div>
<?            }
?>          </div>
            </li>

<?          if ($d->get_info('water and drag')) {
?>              <li class="waterAndDragRow" style="display:block;">
                  <span class="wdStartTime">08:33am</span> -
                  <span class="wdEndTime">08:34am</span>
                  <input type="text" class="wdDescription" value="<?= $d->get_info('water and drag description') ?>">
                </li>
<?          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing bad in short tags. It's just a configuration option.

Comment: +1 for short tags. May the PHP devs who've ever thought about deprecating or eliminating them reconsider their foolishness.

Comment: Short tags aren't portable.  Something to be aware of before you choose to do this.

Comment: @banzaimonkey it IS portable. Just turn it on. It's not as hard as it seems.

Comment: @Col.: Yes, it can be turned on, but remember not everyone has control over their servers.

Comment: @Marcel and so what? Not everyone have PHP installed on their server. Or, say, a mod_rewrite. Is it a reason not to use it at all? The most portable web application is pure HTML one. Any other technology shouldn't be used because of that "not portable" fear. There are hundreds of configuration options in PHP. Why so much concern in that one?

Comment: @Col: I was talking about creating web sites on one server (e.g., on my local running server or my own host) that have to run on another one in the end. I've seen lots of servers running Apache & PHP with many different configurations. In most cases, those run on hosting providers where I can't tweak parameters. It's really horrible to find out that such a server doesn't accept short tags. That's probably why Banzaimonkey said that they aren't portable: what works in one PHP configuration, might not work in another one.

Comment: Global replace... done. No more short tags. There are also ways to rewrite short tags on the fly if you are on a server with absolutely no way to enable them and you don't want to replace them. Readability is more important.

Comment: @cbednarski This answer has nothing to do with short tags. It would make the same point if `<?` where replaced with `<?php` and `<?=` with `<?php echo`

Answer (score 2):

In regards to PHP classes to generate HTML, you could use http://api20.cakephp.org/class/html-helper an object from the cake PHP framework.
The others have already addressed your not so clean code.

It uses this format: `div( $class = NULL, $text = NULL, $options = array ( ) )`

Answer (score 1):

why not create your own clases?? or at least some functions... and i saw that you use alot of IF, you may clean it using vairables like when you have

```
if($d->get_info('ghost riders')){
            echo '<div class="ghostRidersContainer">Ghost Riders<input type="checkbox" checked class="ghostBox"><input type="text" maxlength="2" class="ghostRiderInput" value="' . $d->get_info('ghost riders') .  '"></div>' . "\n";
        }else{
            echo '<div class="ghostRidersContainer">Ghost Riders<input type="checkbox" class="ghostBox"><input type="text" maxlength="2" class="ghostRiderInput"></div>' . "\n";
        }
```

you could write:

```
$check = ($d->get_info('ghost riders'))?"checked":"";
echo '<div class="ghostRidersContainer">Ghost Riders<input type="checkbox" '.$check.' class="ghostBox"><input type="text" maxlength="2" class="ghostRiderInput" value="' . $d->get_info('ghost riders') .  '"></div>' . "\n";
```

it will look cleaner :) I've created a Form class that helps me when i have to create forms and the code is more legible

Comment: as a matter of fact, ternary operator looks ugly. as well as echoed HTML. But the point itself is right

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix html and php code!
I would do this: https://github.com/HanKruma/Tag-Generator

"Tag gen"

```
<?php

namespace Main;

/**
 * Description of Tag
 *
 * @author HanKrum
 */
class Tag {


    private $_tags = ['doctype', 'br', 'hr', 'input', 'meta', 'base', 'basefont', 'img', 'source'];

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $attr = null;
        $text = null;
        if (\in_array($name, $this->_tags)) {
            $name = $name == $this->_tags[0] ? '!' . $name . ' html' : $name;
            foreach ($arguments as $v) {
                $attr .= ' ' . $v;
            }
            return '<' . $name . $attr . '>' . "\n";
        }
        $br = 0;
        $count = \count($arguments);
        foreach ($arguments as $v) {
            $br ++;
            if ($br == $count) {
                $text = $v;
            } else {
                if (!$v) {
                    $space = null;
                } else {
                    $space = ' ';
                }
                $attr .= $space . $v;
            }
        }
        return '<' . $name . $attr . '>' . $text . '</' . $name . '>' . "\n";
    }

}
```

---

And use this that:

```
<?php
$ob = new \Main\Tag();
echo $ob->input('class="doc"', 'placeholder="Title"', 'name="title"');
echo $ob->span(null, 'Text');
exit($ob->button('class="submit"', 'Write');
```

Comment: nice simple code, how about add a tag inside? like li's inside ul or even better recursively create ul -> li -> li ->ul -> li and so on, this would be great to create menús per example

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for the simple start. This is enough to generate a wide variety of elements.

This will create any kind of element, give some content, a class, and an id.

You will have to handle special cases yourself, if you are using it in your app.

```
<?php
/**
 * HTML - Simplest html element builder 
 * - @param1 Element name
 * - @param2 Class name
 * - @param3 ID
 * - @param2 Element content
 */
class HTML{
    /**
    * Create a new html element
    */ 
    private static function core($element, $content) {
        return "<" . $element . ">" . $content . "</" . $element . ">";
    }
    /**
    * Add a new param to a html element
    */        
    private static function addParam($elem, $param, $value) {
        if (is_null($value)){return $elem;}
        return implode(" $param=\"" . $value . '">', explode(">", $elem, 2));
    }
    /**
    * Return an element with a class and an id
    */
    public static function create($element, $content=null, $class=null, $id=null) {
        return self::addParam(self::addParam(self::core($element, $content), "class", $class) , "id", $id);
    }
}

// Examples
echo HTML::create("div", "This is it!", "redclass", "niceid");
echo PHP_EOL;
$html = new HTML();
echo HTML::create("button", "Click me!", "button", "48151");
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $html->create("p", "A paragraph");
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $html->create("h3", "Hello world!");

// OUTPUT
//<div class="redclass" id="niceid">This is wtf</div>
//<button class="button" id="48151">Click me!</button>
//<p>A paragraph</p>
//<h3>Hello world!</h3>
```

```css
.redclass {background: red}
```

```html
<div class="redclass" id="niceid">This is it!</div>
<button class="button" id="48151">Click me!</button>
<p>A paragraph</p>
<h3>Hello world!</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<?php

    $html->tag('doctype')->alone('html')->tag();
    $html->tag('html')->lang('en');

        $html->tag('head');
            $html->tag('meta')->charset('utf-8')->tag();
            $html->tag('meta')->httpequiv('X-UA-Compatible')->content('IE=edge')->tag();
            $html->tag('meta')->name('viewport')->content('width=device-width, initial-scale=1')->tag();
            $html->tag('meta')->name('description')->content('Brosta Tools')->tag();
            $html->tag('meta')->name('author')->content('Brosta')->tag();
            $html->tag('title')->text('Brosta Tools')->tag();
            $html->tag('link')->href('assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')->rel('stylesheet')->tag();
            $html->tag('link')->href('assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/simple-sidebar.css')->rel('stylesheet')->tag();
            $html->tag('link')->href('assets/plugins/prism/css/prism.css')->rel('stylesheet')->tag();
            $html->tag('link')->href('assets/plugins/normalize/css/normalize.css')->rel('stylesheet')->tag();
            $html->tag('link')->href('assets/plugins/brosta/css/brosta.css')->rel('stylesheet')->tag();

            $html->tag('script')->src('assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/jquery.js')->type('text/javascript')->tag();
            $html->tag('script')->src('assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')->type('text/javascript')->tag();
            $html->tag('script')->src('assets/plugins/prism/js/prism.js')->type('text/javascript')->tag();
            $html->tag('script')->type('text/javascript')->text('$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {e.preventDefault(); $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled"); });')->tag();
            $html->tag('script')->type('text/javascript')->text('
                window.onload = function () { 
                    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("token");
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                        var variable = x[i].getAttribute("class").replace("token ", "");
                        var text = x[i].innerText.trim().replace("$", "");
                        if(!/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(text) || text.indexOf("_") >= 0) {
                            x[i].className +=" " + variable + "-" + text;
                        }
                    }
                }
            ')->tag();
        $html->tag();

        $html->tag('body')->class('brosta');

            $html->include('snippets.brosta.navbar');

            $html->tag('div')->class('container-fluid brosta');
                $html->tag('div')->id('wrapper');
                    $html->tag('div')->id('sidebar-wrapper');
                        $html->tag('ul')->class('sidebar-nav');

                            $data = [
                                ['link' => '/Instalation', 'text' => 'Instalation'],
                                ['link' => '/Html', 'text' => 'Html']
                            ];

                            foreach($data as $link)
                            {
                                $html->tag('li');
                                    $html->tag('a')->href($link['link'])->text($link['text'])->tag();
                                $html->tag();
                            }

                        $html->tag();
                    $html->tag();
                    $html->tag('div')->id('page-content-wrapper');
                        $html->tag('div')->class('row');
                            $html->tag('div')->class('col-lg-12');
                                $html->tag('div')->class('panel panel-default');
                                    $html->tag('div')->class('panel-heading clearfix')->text('Without Time')->tag();
                                    $html->tag('div')->class('panel-body');
                                        $html->tag('p')->text('Make a file in your root public server. Ex: <code class="language-php">C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php</code>')->tag();
                                        $html->tag('pre')->class('language-php');
                                            $html->tag('code')->class('language-php')->text($html->specialChars('views/content.php'))->tag();
                                        $html->tag();
                                    $html->tag();
                                $html->tag();
                            $html->tag();
                        $html->tag();
                    $html->tag();
                $html->tag();
            $html->tag();
        $html->tag();
    $html->tag();

echo $html->get();
```

Comment: That is funny!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but I've recently written [an object-oriented HTML generator for PHP](https://github.com/ricotheque/HTMLizer). It supports nesting.

As an example, this...

```
$h = new \HTML;
echo $h::div(
    'class', 'my-class', 
    'id', 'my-id',
    $h::p(
        'class', 'paragraph',
        'It was a dark and stormy night, at least according to the beginning of the book.'
    )
);
```

...will create this markup (without spaces between the tags)...

```
<div class="my-class" id="my-id">
    <p class="paragraph">It was a dark and stormy night, at least according to the book.</p>
</div>
```

Hope you find it useful!

Answer (score 0):

[studiowbe/html](https://github.com/studiowbe/html) is the right package for me. It has a sound API, with chaining, and it is enabled on Composer.

```
$link = new Studiow\HTML\Element("a");
$link->setInnerHTML("Documents")
        ->setAttribute("href", "/documents")
        ->addClass("button")
        ->addClass("button-documents")
        ->setAttribute('title', "Go to documents");
echo (string) $link; // Outputs <a href="/documents" class="button button-documents" title="Go to documents">Documents</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Tag` and `Attribute` classes are simple to understand and they get the job done.

### A simple usage example with a single tag

```
$div = new Tag("div");

$class = new Attribute("class");
$class->addItem("class_a");
$class->addItem("class_b");

$div->addAttribute($class);

echo $div->build();
/**
 * Output:
 *
 * <div class='class_a class_b'></div>
 */
```

### A more complex usage example with multiple tags

#### a. Creating tags

```
$mainDiv = new Tag("div");
$innerDiv = new Tag("div");
$h1 = new Tag("h1");
$h2 = new Tag("h2");
$h3 = new Tag("h3");
```

#### b. Creating attributes

```
$class = new Attribute("class");
$class->addItem("someClass");

$style = new Attribute("style", ";");
$style->addItem("font-color: blue");
$style->addItem("font-size: 10px");
```

#### c. Adding attributes

```
$innerDiv->addAttribute($class);
$h3->addAttribute($style);
```

#### d. Adding plain text

```
$h1->setPlainText("This is header one");
$h2->setPlainText("This is header two");
$h3->setPlainText("This is header three");
```

#### e. Adding tags

```
$innerDiv->addTag($h1);
$innerDiv->addTag($h2);

$mainDiv->addTag($innerDiv);
$mainDiv->addTag($h3);
```

#### f. Building tags

```php
echo $mainDiv->build();

/**
 * Output (with indentation):
 *
 * <div>
 *   <div class='someClass'>
 *     <h1>This is header one</h1>
 *     <h2>This is header two</h2>
 *   </div>
 *   <h3 style='font-color: blue;font-size; 10px'>
 *     This is header three
 *   </h3>
 * </div>
 */
```

### Tag class

```
<?php
final class Tag
{
    protected array $innerTags = [];

    protected array $attributes = [];

    protected string $plainText = "";

    protected string $tagName;

    public function __construct($tagName)
    {
        $this->tagName = $tagName;
    }

    public function addTag(Tag $t)
    {
        $this->innerTags[] = $t;
    }

    public function addAttribute(Attribute $a)
    {
        $this->attributes[] = $a;
    }

    public function setPlainText(string $plainText)
    {
        $this->plainText = $plainText;
    }

    public function build(): string
    {
        if (empty($this->attributes)) {
            $pattern = "<%s%s>%s</%s>";
        } else {
            $pattern = "<%s %s>%s</%s>";
        }

        return sprintf($pattern,
            $this->tagName,
            $this->buildAttributes(),
            $this->buildInnerContent(),
            $this->tagName
        );
    }

    private function buildAttributes(): string
    {
        $building = [];
        foreach ($this->attributes as $att) {
            $building[] = $att->build();
        }
        return implode(" ", $building);
    }

    /**
     * A Tag cannot have inner tags and plain text at
     * the same time
     */
    private function buildInnerContent(): string
    {
        if (empty($this->innerTags)) {
            return $this->plainText;
        }
        return $this->buildInnerTags();
    }

    private function buildInnerTags(): string
    {
        $building = "";
        foreach ($this->innerTags as $tag) {
            $building .= $tag->build();
        }
        return $building;
    }
}
```

### Attribute class

```
<?php
final class Attribute
{
    private string $name;

    private array $items = [];

    private string $itemSeparator;

    public function __construct(string $name, string $itemSeparator = " ")
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->itemSeparator = $itemSeparator;
    }

    public function addItem(string $item)
    {
        $this->items[] = $item;
    }

    public function build(): string
    {
        $formattedItems = implode($this->itemSeparator, $this->items);
        return "{$this->name}='{$formattedItems}'";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. It would be great if you could explain to us how and why your code solves the OP's problem as code itself is not always easy to read.